# Hover highlight a line using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am currently creating interactive plots with ggplot and plotly in a shiny app that I am working on. 
I am wondering if there is a way to create a ggplotly graph that would highlight a line when the mouse hover over it.

```
set.seed(1)
D = data.table(id = rep((1:100),10), value = rnorm(1000), stratification = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 25))
setkey(D, id)
D = D[, time := 1:10, by = id]

plot = ggplot(data = D, aes(x = time, y = value, group = id, color = stratification) )+
  geom_line()+ 
  theme_classic()  +
  xlab("Time from index (years)") +
  ylab("value") 

ggplotly(plot)
```

Is there a way in this graph, to highlight/bold a line for the corresponding id when the mouse hover over. Is this an option in plotly? If so, is there a way to achieve this with ggplotly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event_data` in shiny, but it redraws the plot on the server so it's quite slow, so I simplified the example by removing some data:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
set.seed(1)
D = data.table(id = rep((1:10),10), value = round(rnorm(100),3), stratification = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 25))
setkey(D, id)
D = D[, time := 1:10, by = id]

shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(plotlyOutput("myplot")), server=function(input, output, session){
output$myplot = renderPlotly({
  p <- ggplot( )+ 
    theme_classic()  +
    xlab("Time from index (years)") +
    ylab("value") 
  hover_line <- event_data("plotly_hover")
  if(!is.null(hover_line)){
    selected <- D[time==hover_line[[3]] & value==hover_line[[4]],.(id,stratification)]
    print(selected)
    p <- p+ geom_line(data = D[id %in% selected$id & stratification %in% selected$stratification,],aes(x = time, y = value, group = id, color = stratification), size=2)
    p <- p+ geom_line(data = D[!(id %in% selected$id & stratification %in% selected$stratification),],aes(x = time, y = value, group = id, color = stratification))
  } else
    p <- p+ geom_line(data = D,aes(x = time, y = value, group = id, color = stratification))

  ggplotly(p)
  })
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without Shiny?